# Ошибка сервера на Heroku

Tags: python, django, сервер, heroku

Есть интернет-магазин, где через модели я добавляю товар. Многие товары добавляются без проблем, но некоторые не добавляются, а Heroku выдает ошибку сервера. Что это может быть ? Лог ошибки привел ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это может быть всё, что угодно.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но решил спросить ибо может кто-то знает или сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: Многие сталкивались с ошибками своих программ на Heroku. И я сталкивался. Даже не знаю, чем вам это помочь может.

Comment: И как вы решили эту проблему ?

Comment: Какую именно? У меня их было с десяток разных, если не больше.

Comment: если вы не поняли, то Сергей иронизировал, приложите, пожалуйста, скрин с ошибками

Comment: я понял иронию) там просто ошибка сервера

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, когда задаете такие вопросы, приводите трейсбэк ошибки, модель товара, форму добавления и представление страницы добавления товара. Вероятнее всего, ошибка в вашем коде, а не в Heroku.

Если вы используете gunicorn, используйте команду `sudo journalctl -u {file_name}`, чтобы просмотреть логи. В конце вы увидете traceback ошибки.

Попробуйте запустить проект django на локальном сервере aka своем компьютере. Повторите действия при которых возникла ошибка и в консоли отоброзится подробный traceback.

Почитайте подробнее про настройку сервера. Возможно, вы где-то допустили ошибку. [Вот пример](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru) хорошей статьи от DigitalOcean

Comment: Да, мне следовало бы добавить лог ошибки (что я и сделал выше). Но я, все же, склонен к тому, что это ошибка на стороне сервера Heroku, хотя не уверен до конца. И вот почему:
1. У меня на локальном сервере все добавляется прекрасно без ошибок
2. До этого момента все товары добавлялись без ошибок ( я добавил около 140 товаров), потом же начала вылазить ошибка сервера, и то не каждый раз, а как-то рандомно. То есть я могу добавить 3 товара, а на след. товаре может вылезти эта ошибка и товар не добавится. 

Ошибка выглядит примерно так:

"Server Error 500" и все.

Comment: Заметил еще одно.Когда добавил продукт и он не добавился, я попробовал заменить фото, которые я загружал, и после продукт уже добавлялся. Так что, скорее всего, проблема может быть в фото, которые я загружал.

Comment: Это вполне возможно. Будет проще, если вы приведете все остальные фрагменты кода, которые могут быть связаны с ошибкой. Мне бы хотелось взглянуть на модель, форму и представление. Попробуйте включить на сервере `Debug`, если вы его не используете, и поймать ошибку снова. Вместо `Server Error 500` должен появиться traceback